Why does running an iOS app through macOS cause "Failed to look up symbolic reference" crash?
I'm trying to run an iOS app natively using macOS, now that Apple-Silicon-based Macs support running iOS apps natively. But for some reason when I ran the app, right after it finishes launching it will crash and gave me this error log.

Failed to look up symbolic reference at 0x106289ecf - offset 2378665 - symbol symbolic _____Sg 14MarketplaceKit14AppDistributorO in /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ayqzzwghuzgzzwgxomvkxxoubhxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/.XCInstall/AppName.app/Wrapper/AppName.app/AppName

I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything other than work on the app. I've done some research but I haven't gotten any working answers. I also cleaned the build folder, deleted the DerivedData folder, restarted my Mac, and reinstalled Xcode, but the error still exists. How do I solve this?

I found that based on this, this was caused by Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK. This only happened in macOS 14.5 and 14.6 (as I'm writing this answer). I had to set the Google Ads SDK to version 11.1.0 and run pod update. It solves the crash.

I've tried all minor versions of the v11 SDK and they all fail to launch on macOS, albeit the error is slightly different on earlier versions. The root of the issue is that the new Apple MarketplaceKit framework is just not available on macOS even when running iOS apps, while it is on iOS. Google probably needs to add a workaround for this.

Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 11.5.0 worked for me.

11.8.0 did not work but 11.5.0 worked for me as well.

Check Framework Linking:
Ensure "MarketplaceKit" and "AppDistributor" are correctly linked to your target.
Verify their presence in the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section of your target settings.

Unfortunately this doesn't help. I still get the same crash. Do you have any other suggestions?
